# Haskell recurse and add to a list

Tags: list, haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner,

I have a function

```
func :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
func [] = []
func (x:xs) = x + func xs
```

Each recursion I want to append the value to a list for my output. This function will sum consecutive indexes in a list so that the input `[1, 2, 3, 4]` produces `[1, 3, 6, 10]`.

How do I append the value generated each time to my list?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. But yes, you need a stop condition (base case)

Comment: I have edited now

Comment: `0` is not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here isn't how to append, but rather how to calculate the value in the first place. Each item needs to be substituted with a sum of itself with all the items preceding it.

Here is one way to do it:

```
Prelude> func (x:xs) = x:map (+ x) (func xs); func [] = []
Prelude> func [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1,3,6,10]
```

How does this work? We're given a list that starts with the element `x` and has the remaining elements `xs`. We want to increment every item in `xs` by `x`, after recursively applying the algorithm to `xs`.

This is what `x:map (+ x) (func xs)` does. It reads as "prepend `x` to the result of mapping every element in `func xs` through an increment by `x`".

---

E.g. for `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, we want `1` to be added to every member of the result of recursively applying the algorithm to `[2, 3, 4]`, then prepended. For `[2, 3, 4]` we want `2` to be ... to `[3, 4]`. And so on, until eventually for `[4]` we want `4` to be added and prepended to the result of applying the algorithm to `[]`.

This is where our base case (`func [] = []`) kicks in: the algorithm is defined so that it returns an empty list unchanged. Hence `func [4]` is `[4]`, `func [3, 4]` is `[3, 7]`, and you keep incrementing and prepending until you get `[1,3,6,10]`.

Comment: @JamesHamish Sure, I'll expand the answer. I should mention that the more idiomatic way to do this is `scanl`, as shown in the other answer, so you might want to use/accept that.

Answer (score 4):

I think in this particular case, you could use `scanl1` like:

```
scanl1 (+) [1,2,3,4] -- [1,3,6,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over lists, we often use folds, which is a way of reducing the list to a particular value.

There's also another type of operation, which is a fold that collects all results along the way, and that's called a `scan` (from the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl)):

```
scanl                   = scanlGo
  where
    scanlGo           :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]
    scanlGo f q ls    = q : (case ls of
                               []   -> []
                               x:xs -> scanlGo f (f q x) xs)
```

So the scan takes three arguments: a function that takes two values and returns a value, a starter value, and a list of values.

The scan will then return a list.

Thus, what you need is a function that takes two values and returns something of the same type as the first (it's okay if both are the same). Binary addition would work here: `+`.

You also need a value to start off with (the `b`, which is the second argument to our function), and 0 is the identity for integer addition, so we should use that.

Finally, we pass your list to get the result.

Try to figure out how to write you function as a fold and then as a scan and you will discover the answer.